# make_shared in a try catch - scoping issue

Tags: c++

I need to allocate memory, but I would like to do this in a try/catch, but that introduces a new scope, in which the variable is then not available once I'm out of the try-scope. What's the best way to solve this?

```
try {
    auto something = std::make_unique<SomeClass>;
} 
catch (std::bad_alloc) {
    ...
}
// ... lots of code I don't want to include in the try/catch-scope.
something.callSomeMethod();
```

How to I go about solving this?

Comment: Why don't you want to put that code in the try scope? That's the correct way to solve this.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> something;` above your try, then in your try : `something = std::make_unique<SomeClass>;`

Comment: Well, due to code readability.... But I guess I should extract the "...lots of code"-part into a method, and then call that method within the same try catch-part.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley try bodies must be as narrow as possible; otherwise you will catch exceptions you shouldn't be catching.

Comment: @elyse: That's obviously wrong, because "as narrow as possible" is no try block at all. The try block obviously needs to be wide enough to encompass the usage of the objects created in it.

Comment: ok pedant, how about "as narrow as possible retaining semantics"

Comment: @elyse: In that case, my original comment was correct, and fits that requirement.

Comment: And you need to put this single allocation into a try-catch-block because of 1) It is the only thing you do in the main function? 2) Because the success of this allocation is optional? 3) Because you're suffering from the wrong mindeset for C++EH?: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#mindset-for-proper-use-of-eh

Comment: @BenjaminLindley no, it changes the semantics since it starts catching exceptions thrown by expressions that aren't `std::make_unique<SomeClass>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a specific reason why what you are doing *shouldn't* work.  If the code you wrote worked the way you wrote it, then you would be calling `callSomeMethod()` on a null object.  The right way to do it as Benjamin Lindley said, is to put that code in your try block.  That way the variable is in-scope but the method call will only happen if there was not a bad alloc that threw an exception.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm a particularly bad code design at the moment, as I was about to do a 'return' in the catch clause, and thus never considered that calling "callSomeMethod()" on a 'dead' object later on is a stupid design.

Comment: Putting more code in the try body catches more exceptions, which may not be desired, and also obscures the exception of which expression you're interested in. -1

Comment: @elyse, Can you explain your point?  If you put the code in the try block but there is an exception from bad alloc, the code will throw and catch as it should.  If there is not a problem, then it can call the method just fine.  If your concern is that the method will throw, then you need another nested try or better design.  Its true that you don't want to put a bunch of potentially-throwing code in one try block, but that is not the question on hand.

Comment: Redesigned the code, and now everything's in the "try" part, and have refactored most of the code so that the try block is smaller, and more readable.

Answer (score 2):

For posterity, and in case you needed to do something else in your `try` block that would *not* result in an invalid pointer (because, as has been mentioned there is a reason what you're trying to do doesn't work). If you're trying to do something else and still want to execute your operations on `something` afterward, the following code will do what you want:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <memory>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    class SomeClass { public: int a; void callSomeMethod() const {} };

    std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> something{};

    try {
        something = std::move(std::make_unique<SomeClass>());

        // operation that might throw other_exception
    }
    catch (const other_exception& e) {
        std::cout << "bad" << std::endl;
    }
    // ... lots of code I don't want to include in the try/catch-scope.
    something->callSomeMethod();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to do that, you'd better return from the function in the catch clause. Otherwise you are calling `callSomeMethod` on a null pointer.

Comment: Yeah, that's a possibility, but I think i'll just refactor the code, as there is no particular reason to do any work on 'something' if the mem-alloc fails.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I tried to clarify a bit what I meant in an edit. This isn't a big-use scenario, but I wanted to show what you would do if it came up.

Comment: for pity's sake, put an `if` statement around the call through `something` - it could be null!

Comment: @RichardHodges Unless I'm forgetting something from just four hours ago, not in this example (and it really is just an example). If `make_unique` throws `bad_alloc` somewhere along the line, the exception won't be caught and will bubble up the stack.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have mentioned, your code should generally be within the `try/catch` block, since it doesn't have any meaning if the exception is caught.  I'm not sure what your reason is for not wanting to include the code in the `try/catch`, since you're implying `something.callSomeMethod()` depends on `lots of code`, and `lots of code` depends on `std::make_unique`.  If `lots of code` isn't dependent, you can delay `std::make_unique` until after `lots of code`.

I think it might be worth clarifying, the purpose of exceptions is to abort and handle an exceptional situation.  The exceptional situation is that execution of following code can be impacted.  So, any code that would be impacted, or transitively code that depends on it, should be included in the `try/catch` block.  This is the minimal scope, by definition, and it's the scope you should use.  Nothing more, nothing less.

Sometimes the code to handle an exception can be shared across functions that throw exceptions, but it's still generally best to narrow the scope and write the necessary specific handling code for each one.

It might be worth noting that almost nothing can be done for `std::bad_alloc`, so it's generally not an exception worth catching.  Also, you should generally catch exceptions by reference unless you have a reason to do otherwise.  So, your code should look something like this...

```
try {

    auto something = std::make_unique<SomeClass>;    

    // ... lots of code I don't want to include in the try/catch-scope.

    something.callSomeMethod();
}

catch (std::exception& e) {

    // you dun goofed...
}
```

Comment: I read somewhere sometime that you should allocate a tiny bit of memory which you can release in a "catch (std::bad_alloc) "-statement, so that you  have some memory which you can use in order to inform the user of this and that, is that a good or bad idea?

Comment: Normally it's done without allocating memory (e.g. `std::cout`, `std::cerr`, exit status, uncaught exception, etc...).  The best thing to do is to just never exhaust memory though, which should be virtually impossible as long as you use memory reasonably.  Although just for future reference, it's usually better not to switch answers.

Comment: This is an application with a gui, thus std:cout etc isn't very useful. 

Regarding the 'changing answer' bit, I was supposed to upvote your reply, not 'answer' it, guess I hit the wrong button, I'll change it back now.

Comment: It's probably debatable.  The user knows the application crashed, do they need to know why?  If they need to know why, are the system logs good enough?  Will the operating system catch OOM and kill the application anyway?  Will the operating system report the OOM event, and so on.  It might be a useful trick, but I don't think there's a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must use `something` outside the try/catch block (and no, you really mustn't, but if you insist...) then it's a good idea to make it impossible to give yourself a segfault.

calling a method on a null unique_ptr is a sure way to disaster, plus the initialisation of the unique_ptr requires an un-necessary memory allocation.

Another way is to use boost::optional :

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/optional.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    class SomeClass { public: int a; void callSomeMethod() const {} };

    boost::optional<SomeClass> something{};

    try {
        something = SomeClass();

        // operation that might throw other_exception
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "bad" << std::endl;
    }
    // ... lots of code I don't want to include in the try/catch-scope.
    if (something) {
        something.get().callSomeMethod();
    }
    return 0;
}
```